# What’s the best android widget for an image to allow zooming and drawing over the image?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I’m making an app of the Ticket to Ride board game. I need to display a map of the US. I want to be able to zoom in and out on the map, “draw” trains over the top of the image, and listen for clicks at a specific location on the image.

Can anyone give me some direction on how to implement this? Is there a widget that has the functionality I’m looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this [SubsamplingScaleImageView](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view)